# Match a string with multiple patterns and return the matched pattern in php

Tags: php, regex

I am writing a function which match a string with exact pattern from a list and return matched pattern.

```
$patterns = array(
 'pages/{{name}}/{{id}}',
 'profile/{{id}}',
 'download_{{file}}-{{id}}'
);
```

Now i have a string

```
$string = 'download_finalbuild_123';
```

i want to compare this string and return the matched pattern. So i used a foreach statement

```
foreach($patterns as $pattern){
   $matched_pattern = '';
   if(match_pattern($pattern,$string){
     $matched_pattern = $pattern;
     break;
   }
}
echo 'Matched pattern is ' . $matched_pattern;
```

Now i want a function match_pattern which return true if pattern matches with string.

```
function match_pattern($first,$second){
   //Some magic here which return true if both parameters match
}
```

Comment: Are you just looking for [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i tried preg_match but because i have place holder in patterns and real value in string. but i want php to match to which pattern this string matches

Comment: I think the answer is just loop through the array of patterns and use preg_match to see if there is a match, and push those to the resulting array.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you please provide sample code for match_pattern function?

Comment: What is the output you expect? What characters do the `{{file}}`, `{{id}}`, `{{name}}` can consist of?

Comment: I just want function to return true if a pattern matched the string

Comment: But you do not have a regular expression pattern defined in your `pattern` array. Right now, your question is unclear. Again, what characters do the `{{file}}`, `{{id}}`, `{{name}}` can consist of? Word characters? Alphanumeric only? Any chars other than `/`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sir because they are place holder that i need in other function. My question is that I want to check if  string is similar to the pattern provided.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sir like url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35695137/match-a-string-with-multiple-patterns-and-return-the-matched-pattern-in-php has a pattern http://stackoverflow.com/questions/{{question_id}}/{{question_title}}

Comment: [Are you looking for this](https://3v4l.org/BZQRn)

Comment: @Uchiha yes. thanks :)

Comment: You were asking the correct question but OP didn't get it though @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: [Should “Give me a regex that does X” questions be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed/285739#285739) x 3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes. i modified my array and now it works

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've deleted my answer.

Comment: @Uchiha: You do not have to, I do not downvote working answers. I hope others won't either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prepare an array of regex patterns and need to use it within `foreach` and `preg_match` like as

```
$patterns = array(
 'pages\/[a-zA-Z]+\/[\d]+',
 'profile\/[\d]+',
 'download_[a-zA-Z]+_[\d]+'
);

$string = 'download_finalbuild_123';
$str = "";
foreach($patterns as $v){
    if(preg_match("/$v/",$string)){
        $str .= "Match string matches $v pattern";
    }
}

echo $str;
```

**Output**

```
Match string matches download_[a-zA-Z]+_[\d]+ pattern
```